# How to save an animation without showing the previous frames in the video?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I would like to save an animation using Python but I get the frames superposed! I want to get the frames displayed individually.
Please here what I used:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
from numpy import pi, cos, sin

fig = plt.figure()
plt.axis([-1.5, 1.5,-1.5, 1.5])
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_aspect(1)

N=100

xp = [None] * N
yp = [None] * N

def init():
    # initialize an empty list of cirlces
    return []

def animate(i):

    xp[i]=sin(i*pi/10)
    yp[i]=cos(i*pi/10)

    patches = []

    patches.append(ax.add_patch( plt.Circle((xp[i],yp[i]),0.02,color='b') ))
    return patches 

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=N-1, interval=20, blit=True)

anim.save("example.avi")
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't have any experience with this but have you tried a tutorial like [this one](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/)? If that works, then what is different between it and your code? Please update your question with just enough code to reproduce what you see. For example, a simple way to get `fig`, `animate`, `init` and `N` - not a giant block of code - as simple as possible.

Comment: @kobejohn Thank you for your comment. I have just included a minimal working environment. As you can see from the program, the particle rotate around the origin but I would like to display the particle current position and not the history (trajectory). Do you have any idea?

Comment: That looks much better! I don't have time to look now but I'll +1 for your update to get other people interested. If you can find any sample videos on youtube that demonstrate something similar to what you hope to see, that will probably also help.

Comment: @kobejohn Okay thank you for your up-voting! When I display the video I get the history of the particle. I am more interested in the current position. I hope one would have a look on it! best!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some things I'm not sure about and it really seems to be that the axis.plot() behavior and FuncAnimate() behavior are different. However, the code below works for both.

## Use only one patch (in your case)

The key point from your code is that you are adding a new circle in addition to the old circles every iteration:

```
patches = []
patches.append(ax.add_patch( plt.Circle((xp[i],yp[i]),0.02,color='b') ))
```

Even though you clear the patches list, they are still stored in the axis.

Instead, just create one circle and change its position.

## Clear first frame with `init()`

Also, `init()` needs to clear the patch from the base frame.

## Standalone Example

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
from numpy import pi, cos, sin

fig = plt.figure()
plt.axis([-1.5, 1.5, -1.5, 1.5])
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_aspect(1)
N = 100
xp = []
yp = []


# add one patch at the beginning and then change the position
patch = plt.Circle((0, 0), 0.02, color='b')
ax.add_patch(patch)
def init():
    patch.set_visible(False)
    # return what you want to be cleared when axes are reset
    # this actually clears even if patch not returned it so I'm not sure
    # what it really does
    return tuple()


def animate(i):
    patch.set_visible(True)  # there is probably a more efficient way to do this
    # just change the position of the patch
    x, y = sin(i*pi/10), cos(i*pi/10)
    patch.center = x, y
    # I left this. I guess you need a history of positions.
    xp.append(x)
    yp.append(y)
    # again return what you want to be cleared after each frame
    # this actually clears even if patch not returned it so I'm not sure
    # what it really does
    return tuple()


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=N-1, interval=20, blit=True)
# for anyone else, if you get strange errors, make sure you have ffmpeg
# on your system and its bin folder in your path or use whatever
# writer you have as: writer=animation.MencoderWriter etc...
# and then passing it to save(.., writer=writer)
anim.save('example.mp4')
plt.show()
```

## Return values???

Regarding the return values of `init()` and `animate()`, It doesn't seem to matter what is returned. The single patch still gets moved around and drawn correctly without clearing previous ones.

Comment: Thank you so much for your powerful answer kobejohn! You're the best!!

Comment: @Strömungsmechanik I'm glad it worked. The documentation and behavior is pretty confusing.